# Java gerar JSON a partir de uma string

Tags: java, json

Sou iniciante em programação e nunca trabalhei com json estou fazendo um trabalho sobre e grafos e para fazer a representação gráfica do grafo preciso gerar um json com os dados do grafo, fiz um método que retorna uma string com o conteudo que eu preciso no json, gostaria de saber como posso gerar o arquivo json a partir do retorno desse método.

Comment: Poste seu código para tentarmos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Se você já fez a parte mais difícil, que é fazer o JSON (string), então criar o arquivo é moleza - abra ele pra escrita e escreva a string nele! Um arquivo JSON é um arquivo de texto, e só (mas eu acho que a codificação tem que ser UTF-8, não tenho certeza). Nada de especial. (ou entendi errado, e você ainda não montou o JSON?)

Comment: Obrigado fiz o que você me disse peguei a string ja com o formato do json e escrevi um arquivo resolvendo o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Se você já fez o método que retorna uma String, basta colocá-la no formato JSON.

Uma alternativa seria gerar um JSON, a partir de um objeto, veja abaixo:

Caso esteja utilizando Maven no seu projeto, você pode incluir essas duas bibliotecas como dependência:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Ou simplesmente baixá-las e incluir no seu projeto.

E o código seria algo assim: 
Uma classe com os atributos

```
public class Person{
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

E seu método:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Person person = new Person();

person.setName("Name");
person.setAge(12);

try {
      String out = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
      System.out.println(out);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Já consegui resolver usei a classe FileWriter e escrevi no arquivo o conteudo da string e salvei como .json resolvendo o problema.